# toggle li in jquery

Tags: jquery, html-lists, toggle

I have the following list:

```
<ul id="tree" class="main-bur-list">
    <li class="top-role-list role_ABM">
        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="2" data-user_id="189984" data-isfetched="1">abhishek.j@asda(ABM - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
        <ul id="tree" class="main-bur-list">
            <li class="top-role-list role_TL">
                <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="3" data-user_id="141590" data-isfetched="1">irfanbaig@gfdgdf(TL - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
                <ul id="tree" class="main-bur-list">
                    <li class="top-role-list role_ISM">
                        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="4" data-user_id="185359" data-isfetched="0">neelamtest2112@gmail.com(ISM - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="top-role-list role_ISM" style="display: list-item;">
                        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="4" data-user_id="164909" data-isfetched="0">mohan.krishna@dggdfm(ISM - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="top-role-list role_ISM" style="display: list-item;">
                        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="4" data-user_id="174582" data-isfetched="0">ritwik.m@sdfsd(ISM - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
                    </li>
                    <li class="top-role-list role_ISM" style="display: list-item;">
                        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="6" data-bu_id="1" data-role="4" data-user_id="194026" data-isfetched="0">Wasim.s@fdsfs(ISM - PMP, CISSP - East Coast)</div>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="top-role-list role_ABM">
        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="9" data-bu_id="1" data-role="2" data-user_id="176794" data-isfetched="0">sachin.k@dfsfsd(ABM - CTFL, Cloud, Prince 2, FRM, CFA (All US))</div>
    </li>
    <li class="top-role-list role_ABM">
        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="7" data-bu_id="1" data-role="2" data-user_id="189984" data-isfetched="0">abhishek.j@dasdas(ABM - PMP, CISSP - West Coast)</div>
    </li>
    <li class="top-role-list role_ABM">
        <div class="bu-represent-role" data-sbu_id="7" data-bu_id="1" data-role="2" data-user_id="189984" data-isfetched="0">abhishek.j@dasdsa(ABM - PMP, CISSP - West Coast)</div>
    </li>
</ul>
```

all ul and li are dynamically creating. Now if I click on a li then the child li(s) should be toggling. I am trying by the following piece of code, but it is not working:

```
$('.bu-represent-role').click(function(){
        $('.main-bur-list ul li').next().toggle();
});
```

How to sort this issue?

UPDATE:
http://jsfiddle.net/srimanta12/F4apy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use `.on` method. [JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/F4apy/4/)

```
$('body').on('click', '.bu-represent-role', function (e) {
    $(e.target).next().toggle();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are dynamically generating the `ul`s and `li`s, `click` won't work here. Use [on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead -

```
$(document).on('click', '.bu-represent-role', function(){
    $('.main-bur-list ul li').next().toggle();
});
```

Comment: But in this case some records are not hidding.See the FIddle link in the question.

Answer (score 0):

There were a few errors, but it works like this:

```
$(document).on('click', '.bu-represent-role', function (e) {
    $(e.target).next().toggle();
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/F4apy/2/